# How can I fix this "String index out of range error"?

Tags: java, runtime-error

I am having trouble fixing this error in a program I'm writing for school. I've pasted the java snippet below along with the error I receive after running the code.

---

Java snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     String largeSpace = " ";
     String smallSpace = " ";
     //Printing header row
     System.out.print("Title" + largeSpace.substring("Title".length()));
     System.out.print("ISBN" + smallSpace.substring("ISBN".length()));
     System.out.print("Course" + smallSpace.substring("Course".length()));
     System.out.print("Enrollment" + 
     smallSpace.substring("Enrollment".length()));
     System.out.print("To Order");
     System.out.println();
     BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
```

---

Error I receive:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String 
index out of range: -4
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
    at A5WilliamCarter.main(A5WilliamCarter.java:102)
```

Comment: `length()` is (last index + 1) already.

Answer (score 0):

Since "Title".length() is 5, and largeSpace only has length 1, and 5 is more than 1, then it will throw a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. You are 4 characters short.

I'm not completely sure what you're doing, but I think a possible fix would be the following:

```
    System.out.print("Title" + largeSpace*("Title".length()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning `String largeSpace = " ";` and then trying to get a substring of it starting at index 5, leaving you 4 characters short.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you are doing with

```
largeSpace.substring("Title".length())
smallSpace.substring("ISBN".length())
```

This is because largeSpace and smallSpace each have length 1, but you are trying to get a substring starting at characters 4 and 5. This will raise the error. I am not sure what you are trying to do with this code so I can't provide a fix.